# Hyperledger Composer Rest Server - POST Request Timeout

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

i'm facing a problem related to the composer-rest-server v.0.18.1.

The composer-rest-server is connected to a running blockchain on the IBM Blockchain - Started Plan.

Is working fine but after a while (6-7 hours) the POST requests return an 500 error

> (Error: Error trying invoke business network. Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT)

instead the GET requests still work fine (i'm able to retrieve the data from the blockchain).

I tried to bypass the composer-rest-server by submitting a transaction directly from the composer-cli (v.0.18.1) and it worked fine.

Does anyone have an idea about this error?
Thanks.

Comment: I would raise a ticket within the IBM Cloud system.